# Python KEY ERROR

Tags: python

The error that is generated is:

```
  File "/home/tweet_v8/tweetSum/Summarizer/Sentence.py", line 42, in _tfIdfSentence
    w.append( self.lsa.getCell(doc, self.vectorSpace.keywords()[(term,)]) )     
KeyError: (u'l.a.',)
```

The function is written like:

```
# tf-idf computation for one sentence
def _tfIdfSentence (self, sent, doc):
    w = []  
    for term in sent:
        w.append( self.lsa.getCell(doc, self.vectorSpace.keywords()[(term,)]) )     
    #print sent
    if max(w) > 0:
        #print [float(i)/max(w) for i in w], w, doc, sent
        return [float(i)/max(w) for i in w]
    else:
        return [0]
```

i don't know what is the problem with this line of code.

```
w.append( self.lsa.getCell(doc, self.vectorSpace.keywords()[(term,)]) )
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: We cannot help you this way. The key you're trying to get doesn't exist, and as we don't know what your dict is like, i don't think it's easy to help you.

Comment: Have you tried this? `w.append( self.lsa.getCell(doc, self.vectorSpace.keywords()[term]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given a `KeyError` because the searched dict key, `(u'l.a.',)`, was not found in `self.vectorSpace.keywords()` dictionary.

To avoid the `KeyError`, use `dict`'s `get()` to set a default value if the key you are searching for doesn't exist:

```
w.append( self.lsa.getCell(doc, self.vectorSpace.keywords().get((term,), 'default') )
```

You would replace `'default'` with whatever value you need.

Another approach is to use [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 0):

`KeyError: (u'l.a.',)`

Python is telling you that the key (of a key/value pair for a dictionary) "l.a." of type unicode does not exist.

You can wrap that in a try/except KeyError if you just want it set to *something*.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're experiencing is called `KeyError` for a reason, and without a reproducible code sample, we cannot hope to understand *what* you're doing wrong. But, one *can* explain to you what `KeyError` is:

```
>>> d = {'a': 'happy'}
>>> d['a']
'happy'
>>> d['something_that_does_not_exist']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'something_that_does_not_exist'
```

You see, what you have is a *dictionary*, or commonly known as a *hash-map*. Now, when an key does not exist in a hash-map, you get a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, *self.vectorSpace.keywords()* returns a dictionary. You expect this dictionary to contain a certain value - which it does not. Or it contains the value - but in non-unicode form.
Try using *str(term)* instead of *term*
A bit of efficiency improvmenet:

```
kew_words = self.vectorSpace.keywords()
for term in sent:
    try:
        w.append(self.lsa.getCell(doc, key_words[(str(term),)]
    except KeyError:
        <do some stuff>
```

it will help if you print *key_words* - and check its contents